# Using 'this' keyword in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I like to think I understand JavaScript, but I found something unexpected today and I was hoping someone could explain to me why it happens.

Take this code

```
var animalData = {
                  cow:"cow",
                  sheep:"sheep",
                  getCow:function()
                  {
                    return this.cow;
                  },
                  animalList:[
                          {
                            animalId:this.cow,
                            label:"This is a cow"
                          },
                          {
                            animalId:this.sheep,
                            label:"This is a sheep"
                          }
                       ]
          };

console.log(animalData.getCow());
console.log(JSON.stringify(animalData.animalList,null," "))
```

The output is not what I was expecting. Calling `animalData.getCow()` results in `"cow"` just as you would expect. But it's what gets return by the second `console.log` that confuses me.

```
[
 {
  "label": "This is a cow"
 },
 {
  "label": "This is a sheep"
 }
]
```

In other words, the object removes the `animalId` property entirely from the objects defined. I was expecting this

```
[
 {
  "animalId":"cow",
  "label": "This is a cow"
 },
 {
   "animalId":"sheep",
  "label": "This is a sheep"
 }
]
```

And I could understand maybe this

```
[
 {
   "animalId":undefined,
  "label": "This is a cow"
 },
 {
   "animalId":undefined,
  "label": "This is a sheep"
 }
]
```

But why does the `animalId` property get removed entirely?

Can anyone explain what's going on under the surface to cause this behaviour? I'm guessing that the `this` keyword does not work because the properties are undefined when it is invoked, but why does it remove the property entirely?

NB: I'm not looking for a workaround, that's easy enough to do - just interested in why it happens.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kprzgs8q/)

Comment: On a random note. Why do you use JSON stringify to log an object? Just use console.log/console.dir, that way you can investigate the object easily.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Another way to look at it is that he's just using `console.log` to see the effect of stringifying this object, not that he's stringifying it to log it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox One reason would be that if you log the object directly, when you expand the Object in the console you will get the **current** values, not the values of that Object when it was logged. This is because when simply logging the Object, the browser only saves a reference to that Object, not a deep copy of the current Object.

Comment: @Cristy The current values? I had always been under the assumption it shows the values at the time of logging. If I change the values of a previously logged object and inspect the values, I'm pretty sure they don't change.

Comment: @evolutionxbox They can sometimes depending on exactly what's going on.  When it happens (in Chrome at least), you get a little blue `i` next to the object with a hover text very much along the lines of what Cristy said in their comment.

Comment: @Cristy thanks for assuming I am more intelligent that I am. The actual reason is that for a long time I have used my own logging utility method which used to handle browser compatibility and prepend a timestamp to output to help me debug my code (which is often very heavy front end processing). Its normally useful, but it means objects get logged as strings, and I need to stringify. Never been a problem before today, but there's always a first. I think it's time to stop using it and go native :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Simple example - run this in your console: `var o = { x: {y: 3}}; console.log(o); o.x.y = 5;` when it was logged, `o.x.y` was 3, but when you expand it, you see it shows as 5.

Comment: Wow. I seem to be learning basic things every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the point the object is initialised, `this` refers to the outer context, which won't have `cow` and `sheep` properties.  As you thought, that will result in the `animalId`s being `undefined`.

[`JSON.stringify` does certain things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with `undefined` properties, namely:

> If `undefined`, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either **omitted (when it is found in an object)** or censored to `null` (when it is found in an array).

Which is why you don't see them.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for a clear explanation. I didn't know that about JSON.stringify. It can make debugging difficult. I will use something like
JSON.stringify(animalData.animalList, function(k, v) { return (v===undefined)? null : v; });
);

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you are correct your last example, this is what you are trying to stringify:

```
[
 {
   "animalId":undefined,
  "label": "This is a cow"
 },
 {
   "animalId":undefined,
  "label": "This is a sheep"
 }
]
```

And, because those values are undefined `JSON.stringify` simply omits them.
Why the values above are undefined is because the `this` keyword in `this.cow` refers to the current scope, which is actually the `window` Object as it is not inside any other function.

Why it makes sense to omit keys with `undefined` values? Because whether they exist or not, if you try to access `object.key` you will get the correct value: `undefined`

Comment: If you don't instantiate the animalData object with `new`, won't `this` always refer to the `window`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It depends.  The `getCow` function will reference the correct `this` because it's being called as a function on the object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox His `animalData` is not a class that can be instantiated with new, but a simple `Object`. You can't instantiate an `animalData` object (it has no constructor defined).

Comment: Then does that mean `this` will never refer to anything other than `window` in this case?

Comment: offtopic: Look at my rating: 6,666 :D

Comment: Just saved you by upvoting. You won't get dragged through the gates of hell now.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - If you look at the JSFiddle I attached you will see that the function always returns the value of the enclosing object. It's not an object which is intended to be newed up - it's kind of emulating Class properties and static methods